# Comparing between two same objects returning false

Tags: string, flutter, list, dart, oop

I have list of objects and I need to see if the new object is already in the list. So, I make condition if the list contains the new object, it's returning false ,even though I print the list and it contains an object with the same data of the new object maybe it is not being compared between objects depending on the data inside them. What's the solution
For example I have this class:

```
class Favorite{
  final Text date;
  final Text time;
  final Text source;
  final Text destination;
  final Text price;

  Favorite(this.date, this.time, this.source, this.destination, this.price);

  // I used this override to print the data inside the object instead of printing 'instance of favorite' to compare the data
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '[$date, $time, $source, $destination, $price]';
  }
}
```

in other class:

```
List<Favorite> list = [];
Favorite favorite = Favorite(
  Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathDateJourney]),
  Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathTimeJourney]),
  Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathSourceCity]),
  Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathDestinationCity]),
  Text(Map<String, dynamic>.from(
      snapshot.value as Map)[Consts.pathPriceJourney]),);
list.add(favorite);
print(list.contains(favorite)); //returning false
print(list[0] == favorite); //returning false
```

the output of printing the list:

```
I/flutter (14458): []
I/flutter (14458): [[Text("2022-10-27"), Text("05:00"), Text("Homs"), Text("Hama"), Text("800 $")]]
I/flutter (14458): [[Text("2022-10-27"), Text("05:00"), Text("Homs"), Text("Hama"), Text("800 $")], [Text("2022-10-27"), Text("05:00"), Text("Homs"), Text("Hama"), Text("800 $")]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all objects in the `dart` language except the primitive data types like string, int, and double... are not equal to each other since no `==` operator is overridden and set to it, and this include also collections like lists, maps...

the `Favorite` class even if you didn't extend the `Object` class, is also an `Object` in `dart`

so:

```
Favorite() == Favorite() // false
```

unless you override the `==` operator of it to set when two objects should be considered equals like this :

```
class Favorite {
  final Text date;
  final Text time;
  final Text source;
  final Text destination;
  final Text price;

  Favorite(this.date, this.time, this.source, this.destination, this.price);


@override
bool operator ==(Object other) {
return other is Favorite && date.toString() == other.date.toString();
}
```

now you just said that every `Favorite` class that has the same `date.toString()` should be equal.

you can set your equals logic in the `==` overriden method. (it's just an example).

so when you write

```
    Favorite fav1 = Favorite(/* properties*/);
    Favorite fav2 = Favorite(/* properties*/)
    fav1 == fav2 // true
```

it will see if they have the same date so, if they are so then it's `true` otherwise it's `false`

now the algorithm you wrote should work.